# Continuous acrobatics in Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills

Knowing that there is no penalty to use acrobatics to move through a threatened area, other than moving at half speed for the normal DC, why not continuously use it to move? And why not attempt to move at full speed for the extra ten penalty on characters who have high bonuses in acrobatics?

Comment: Because you'd look silly cart-wheeling everywhere you go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that just fine. The risk of ever failing the check is what might make you reconsider doing it all the time though:

> If you attempt to move through an enemy’s space and fail the check, you lose the move action and provoke an attack of opportunity. — [*d20PFSRD*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/acrobatics#move-through-threatened-area)

Quite apart from tactical considerations, always adding a skill check to your move actions will also increase how long your turn takes.